# Which is correct, "their name" or "their names"?

Tags: pronouns

I've got a command that says: Point to the items and color them. Say its name.

I'm sure it should be *their* instead of *its*, but I'm not 100% sure if it should be *their name* or *their names*.

Comment: Point to items? With your finger? Anyway, it's plural so it should be their.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my example:

"*Kudos to Jane and Sam. They added their names early to the meeting agenda.*" → 2 students each of them have one name = 2 names. Plural.

This is based on my own logic, not any grammatical rules that I can refer to.

Following the same thinking:

"*Jane and Sam are here. Their mom is waiting outside.*" → 2 kids with the same mom = 1 mom. Singular.

"*Jane and Sam just pulled up. Their cars are outside.*" → 2 people, 2 different cars.

"*Jane and Sam just pulled up. Their car is outside.*" → 2 people together in 1 car.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Items(plural), so you would say their *names*.